# Metaprogramming in awk, convert file to html table format

Tags: bash, awk, metaprogramming

I have the following files:

> table.txt (comma separate)

```
1,Example Title
COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5
BRCC,ACGC,15869,105A,1
BCAS,GAAG,73345,369T,2
```

> template.awk

```
function parse_print(s){
    s = gensub(/^\s+|\s+$/,"","g",s)
    s = gensub(/[\42]/,"\\\\\042","g",s)
    s = gensub(/\$[0-9]+/,"\" & \"","g",s)
    s = gensub(/\$e/,"\" & \"","g",s)
    return s;
}

/^[^%]/{print "print \"" parse_print($0) "\""; next}
/^%BEGIN$|^%END$/{print substr($1,2) "{"; next}
/^%END.+$/{print "}"; next}
{print substr($1,2) "{"}
{
    if($2 == "%FOREACH"){
        pprint = gensub(/(\S+\s+){2}(.*)/,"\\2","g")
        print "for(e=1; e<=NF; ++e) print \"" parse_print(pprint) "\""
    }else{
        pprint = gensub(/\S+\s+(.*)/,"\\1","g")
        print "print \"" parse_print(pprint) "\""
    }
}
{print "}"}
```

> table.tawk

```
%BEGIN
                    <style>
                        .my_table {border-bottom:3px double black; border-collapse: collapse; }
                        .my_table tr.header{border-bottom:3px double black;}
                        .my_table td{text-align: center;}
                    </style>
                    <table class="my_table">
%ENDBEGIN
%NR==1              <caption>Table $1. $2</caption>
%NR==2              <tr class="header">
%NR>2               <tr>
%NR==2  %FOREACH    <th>$e</th>
%NR>2   %FOREACH    <td>$e</td>
%NR!=1              </tr>
%END
                    </table>
%ENDEND
```

> metaprogramming.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# metaprogram
awk '@include "template"' $1 > .table.awk
awk -vFS="," -f .table.awk $2
rm .table.awk
```

The idea was to use metaprogramming to separate the logic of the presentation, this based in comment of @kent in [How to format text in html using awk's question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41676045/4767343) for to convert text file to html table format.

```
./metaprogramming.sh table.tawk table.txt > table.html
```

this gets,

```html
<style>
.my_table {border-bottom:3px double black; border-collapse: collapse; }
.my_table tr.header{border-bottom:3px double black;}
.my_table td{text-align: center;}
</style>
<table class="my_table">
<caption>Table 1. Example Title</caption>
<tr class="header">
<th>COL1</th>
<th>COL2</th>
<th>COL3</th>
<th>COL4</th>
<th>COL5</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>BRCC</td>
<td>ACGC</td>
<td>15869</td>
<td>105A</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>BCAS</td>
<td>GAAG</td>
<td>73345</td>
<td>369T</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Question 1**

Is there a way to do the calling without creating the temporary file `.table.awk`, even, without to use `bash` script (`awk` direct calling) ?

**Question Bonus**

Is there a way to do this better? is there a library in `awk` that already does this?

Comment: You could always do something like (check the syntax and quotes!) `awk -vFS="," $(awk '@include "template"' $1) $2` to avoid the need for a temp file. What you have seems like a reasonable approach and there is no awk library that does this AFAIK. You should throw a `&&` between commands though to make sure you only do the next one if the previous one succeeded.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks a lot, `awk -vFS="," "$(awk '@include "template"' table.tawk)" table.txt`   does the work, **note**: quotes symbol is required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TXR is a tool which provides a language for template-based extraction and formatting of data, combined with an original Lisp dialect:

In `format.txr` we have:

```
@num,@title
@(coll)@{heading /[^,]+/}@(end)
@(collect)
@  (coll)@{data /[^,]+/}@(end)
@(end)
@(output :filter :tohtml)
<style>
.my_table {border-bottom:3px double black; border-collapse: collapse; }
.my_table tr.header{border-bottom:3px double black;}
.my_table td{text-align: center;}
</style>
<table class="my_table">
<caption>Table @num. @title</caption>
<tr class="header">
@  (repeat)
<th>@heading</th>
@  (end)
</tr>
@  (repeat)
<tr>
@    (repeat)
<td>@data</td>
@    (end)
</tr>
@  (end)
</table>
@(end)
```

We apply it to the `data` file like this:

```
$ txr format.txr data 
<style>
.my_table {border-bottom:3px double black; border-collapse: collapse; }
.my_table tr.header{border-bottom:3px double black;}
.my_table td{text-align: center;}
</style>
<table class="my_table">
<caption>Table 1. Example Title</caption>
<tr class="header">
<th>COL1</th>
<th>COL2</th>
<th>COL3</th>
<th>COL4</th>
<th>COL5</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>BRCC</td>
<td>ACGC</td>
<td>15869</td>
<td>105A</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>BCAS</td>
<td>GAAG</td>
<td>73345</td>
<td>369T</td>
<td>2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Note that the `:filter :tohtml` takes care of escaping characters for HTML; if the data contains `&` for instance, we get `&amp;` and so on.

The vertical `collect` and horizontal `coll` directives implicitly shore up the matched pattern variables into nested lists; `repeat` implicitly unwraps lists, so that just simple variable references like `@data` appear in both the input matching section and in the output.

Here is what that looks like with syntax highlighting under Vim, under which it is very clear what is just template material and what is TXR syntax:

[image: Screenshot of code with syntax coloring]